How to write a review for an obviously bad article?
I have almost no expierence writing reviews and was recently asked (by an established publisher) to review. The review is completely free-form.
The article is just gibberish. I cant even understand a lot of the baldy machine-translated sentences and it is not even clear what the authors were researching. Is it a systematic review? Did they do some new research? I dont know.
Am i expected to provide feedback for all errors and suggestions on how to make this publishable, or can I just write a few sentences on the general state of the article?

Possible duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/195354/63475 Top scoring answer has suggestions for how to review a very bad paper; actually it looks like most of them do.

Thanks, somehow I missed that question.

No worries, I'll mark as duplicate so people searching that find yours first will have a link to follow.
